# Compute $a^2+b^2+c^2$ if...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Compute $a^2+b^2+c^2$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ if you have the following system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}
  a+b+c & = & 57 \\ (a-12c)^2+(10a-3b)^2 & = & 2 
\end{cases}$$

I already know a way to solve this: The second equation tells us that

$$\begin{cases}
  a-12c & = & \pm1 \\ 10a-3b & = & \pm1 
\end{cases}$$

Since the numbers $a,b,c$ must be integers. This, together with the first equation gives us 5 new equations in one system. The only solution with integers is $\{a,b,c\}=\{13,43,1\}$. Thus $$a^2+b^2+c^2=13^2+43^2+1^2=2019.$$

**Question:** is there another interesting way to solve this problem? Doesn't matter if it's harder or more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

A very small improvement: the difference between $a-12c$ and $10a-3b$ is a multiple of $3$, and this eliminates two of the four possible combinations of signs.

Comment: Hi david. Why is it a multiple of 3?

Comment: Yes ofcourse... $a-12c-10a+3b=-9a-9b=-9(a+b)=3(-3)(a+b).$